# SquidGuard holding navigation

Tags: squid, pfsense

This is my first question within ServerFault. So I beg you pardon if the question here is a little out of context or too long. I haven't found anything on the internet so I'm recurring to you.

I'm using a pfSense Firewall v2.2.4 in a virtual machine powered by VirtualBox over a Windows 2003 Server x64 to route internet among approximately 60 LAN users and apply filters to content that can be viewed by them. I've implemented NTLM authentication with Samba and then using its authenticated username to apply my rules in SquidGuard. Everything is working like a charm, except for one thing : some users had reported slow connection through proxy. My machine and some others, which has their internet traffic routed through NAT, doesn't show this behaviour.

I've tried to isolate the problem and found that when I restart Squid services the slowness vanishes instantly. Searching over web I found something related to `url_rewrite_children` Squid parameter. The default is `16 start=8 idle=4` for this version of squidGuard. So I raised them to `32 start=25 idle=5` within **squidguard_configurator.inc** and spent a bunch of time monitoring the services states through command `ps axu | grep -i squidguard`.

The results, when everything seems OK, shows 25 squidGuard processes, which is the expected behaviour but, for some reason, after an interval of 100~120 mins approx, Squid starts 5 more squidGuard processes and then the navigation through proxy slows down. It looks like squidGuard rewriter processes froze or passing through an overload but the processor and memory indicators doesn't show anything weird and system logs doesn't show anything different either.

I've created a Cron task that reconfigure squid every 15 mins with the command `squid -k reconfigure` and other Cron task which restart squid services through command `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/squid.sh restart`. It works, but I think that isn't the ideal solution.

Is there something that I can check or change in squid or squidGuard config files to get rid of this problem ?

My pfSense version is 2.2.4-RELEASE (amd64) built on Sat Jul 25 19:57:37 CDT 2015 (FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE-p15), my squid3 package is on version 0.4.7 and squidGuard-devel package is on version 1.5.10.

pfSense is running over a virtual machine with Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2420 v2 @ 2.20GHz - 4 CPUs: 1 package(s) x 4 core(s) and 4GB of RAM and 240GB of hard disk.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Bruno